# Getting issue while fetching data ASP.NET Core 5.0 & React.JS

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi

Sorry if this quest was asked before, but I am beginner in React.JS and I want to create a small application `ToDoList`.

Once I created the ASP.NET Core 5.0 Web API, I moved to React.JS but when I want to run application I get error message.

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

I am not 100% sure Is this error CORS issue but however in my `Startup.cs` class I add

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });
```

But this wasn't solve the issue.

Here is the service which I try to run

```
const baseUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/todo`;

export const loadTodos = () => {
  return fetch(baseUrl).then((res) => res.json());
};

export const getTodo = (id) => {
  return fetch(`${baseUrl}/${id}`).then((res) => res.json());
};

export const createTodo = (todo) => {
  return fetch(baseUrl, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      title: todo.title,
      completed: todo.completed,
    }),
  }).then((res) => res.json());
};

export const updateTodo = (todo) => {
  return fetch(`${baseUrl}/${todo.id}`, {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      id: todo.id,
      title: todo.title,
      completed: todo.completed,
    }),
  });
};

export const deleteTodo = (id) => {
  return fetch(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, {
    method: "DELETE",
  }).then(res => res.json());
};
```

And also here is ENV

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=https://localhost:3000
```

Also instead of

```
const baseUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/todo`;
```

I used but nothing was happened

```
const baseUrl = `api/todo`;
```

It seems that there is problem that Front-end and Back-end application doesn't have connection between each other but I am not 100% sure where and what should I pay attention.

Does anyone know where I made mistake? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, I try using Postman and when I hit the api I get response but when I run React.JS it seems that there are not connected.

Comment: Well, from here I don't see that it is problem with CORS. 
https://imgur.com/uMt4gy3